# URL rewrite conflicts with ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, url-rewriting

Given an ASP.NET MVC app with some routes enabled. Let them be created by scaffolding with controller name `UsersController`:

```
/users
/users/Details?id=1
...
```

For some reason I need to enable URL Rewrite IIS module **to rewrite** (not redirect) url using the next scheme:

```
/details => /users/Details?id=1
```

Adding the URL Rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="users-rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^details$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/users/Details?id=1"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

produces an error: `"Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory."` any time I call any of ASP.NET MVC helpers like `Html.ActionLink, Url.RouteUrl, etc`.

At the same time redirect (not rewrite) works like a charm.

Is url rewrite module totally incompatible with ASP.NET MVC routing or is there any workaround available?

Comment: _How_ do you call the `Html.ActionLink()` helpers?

Comment: @CodeCaster just like the scaffolder creates them by default: `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id })` ..... `@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")`

Comment: It means that one of the paths has a `..` at the beginning of it that would result in exiting the web site's root folder hierarchy. You might want to update `ActionLink` to details page.

Comment: @MaxBrodin then the application should not work with target url `/users/Details?id=user1` itself, but it does brilliantly when used without URL Rewriting

Comment: We have this issue. MVC routing somehow intercept the request before url rewrite.